# Thread safe way to copy a map

Tags: java, guava

Am using JDK 7, SQLite, and have Guava in my project.

I have a TreeMap with less than 100 entries that is being updated by a single "worker" thread hundreds of times a second. I am now writing a component (another thread - the "DB thread") that will write the map to my database every 5 or 10 seconds.

I know that I need to make a deep copy of the map so the DB thread will use a snapshot, while the worker thread continues its job. I am looking at the [Guava Maps class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) which has many methods that make copies, but I am not sure if any of them meet my needs to synchronize on the map whenever a copy is needed. Is there a method there that will meet my needs, or should I write a synchronized block to make my own deep copy?

Comment: You need a synchronized block. And the worker thread must synchronize as well, on the same lock.

Comment: Unless you can modify the worker threads to honour some kind of lock (excluding them while you're making your copy), this isn't going to work. But surely the worker threads must already have some kind of locking mechanism built into them, so all you need to do is use it for the copying as well.

Comment: No of the Guava `Maps` method does anything similar. David Limkys's answer is right. Actually, you need some `ConcurrentMap` anyway if you want to use it from other threads without synchronization. Concerning the DB thread, you could do something else: Ask the worker thread to create a snapshot and send it to the DB thread. But this is surely more complicated than using `ConcurrentSkipListMap` which is surely good enough.

Comment: @biziclop - no synchronization is being used currently because there is only one worker thread updating the map in a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you want:

If you want a fully concurrent map (cant read while adding and so on) You should use what JSlain said before me.

If all you want is the CURRENT snapshot of the map and you do not care if the map will be modified as long as the iterator you are using wont be changed.

Then use [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)

This will provide each iteration with a new independent iterator so even if the real map is changed you wont notice it.

You will see it in the next update (5 seconds in your case.)

Comment: Wow, didn't know that one. Sounds like what he needs.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I want. You are right when you assumed all I needed was the current snapshot. Makes me wonder how they can do it.. Every modification creates a copy? Can't wait to see how it performs.

Comment: We can check the implementation, but I would assume every requet for an iterator creates a copy.
Its a trade off between performance and the memory.
but having a map with 100 keys, means having 100 copies.(assuming you only add..) I would create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

From [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) javadoc:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access a map 
>       concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be 
>       synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one 
>       or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with an existing key is not a 
>       structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that 
>       naturally encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map should be "wrapped" using 
>       the Collections.synchronizedSortedMap method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent 
>       accidental unsynchronized access to the map:
>
> ```
>    SortedMap m = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap(...));
> ```

Comment: Using a synchronizedSortedMap is not sufficient: the wole block of code doing the copy of the map must be synchronized.

Comment: I think that by using a synchronized map, you can do a copy of it and it'll block other threads trying to access it. That way, you don't have to modify the caller so it uses it with a synchronized block, which makes code stinking.

Comment: Nope. Read the javadoc: *It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned sorted map when iterating over any of its collection views*. A copy obviously iterates over the entries of the map, so it needs to be synchronized.

Comment: Indeed... only use it as David Limkys said, if you use the same map instead of using a copy.