# Which data structure to use to store millions of objects in multithreading environment ( Scalability and performace )?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scalability

My requirement is like : I want to perform **frequent** operation on **millions** of objects in multi-threaded environment with **concurrency and scalability** keeping in mind, I need best data structure suitable for this requirement.

For example :

```
public interface CarDetails {
   public CopyOnWriteArrayList<Car> getAllCars();
   public Car getMostSoldCars(int carModel);
   public void addNewCarDetails(Car car);
   public void oldCardDetails(Car car);
}
```

Initially i had thought to use concurrent API's(**CopyOnWriteArrayList**) as its performs better compared to externally synchronizing the List( **eg: Collections.synchronizedList(list object)**).

**Issue with CopyOnWriteArrayList :** To store millions of objects in memory and performing frequest operations on it has performance impact because CopyOnWriteArrayList creates entirely new List whenever any updation occurs on it and performing such opertions on millions of objects has performance issue. It is good for multiple readers but i am looking for performance on large number of objects.

**Issue with Collections.synchronizedList(list object) :** Externally synchronizing the list has another issue because it locks on entire object which has another performance issue.

Could anyone suggest me , Which collection API's is suitable for this type of requirement( Concurrency , Scalability , Millions of objects , better performance on frequent operation).

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You most probably don't need anything better than a `synchronizedList` wrapper. Have you actually tested the performance of that solution? Also, the choice of the absolutely most optimal structure involves many more details than you have provided, such as: frequency of updates, ratio of reads to writes, actual level of concurrency, and so on.

Comment: Would recommend looking into `concurrentHashMap` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) ``

Comment: test, **test**, **TEST**. Try all approaches and **benchmark**. As @MarkoTopolnik says, start with the simplest solution and improve incrementally - checking every "improvement" with benchmarks. If `synchronizedList` isn't good enough, write a class that `implements List` and wraps an `ArrayList` with a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, I will try to implement (concurrenthashmap and Reentrantreadwritelock) and will compare which performs best for my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is wait-free (i.e. lock-free and threads won't starve) and doesn't perform any copying

If you want to maintain a set instead of a list, then you can have multiple threads add objects to the **ConcurrentLinkedQueue** and have a single thread **poll** the queue and add the objects to an unsynchronized **HashMap**; this may be more efficient than using a **ConcurrentHashMap**.  However this assumes that you can withstand a slight delay between an object being added and the object showing up in the set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best data structure for performance would be a hashMap, it has an O(1) search operation, while an arrayList takes an O(N).

On the concurrency side, I would probably go with the

[ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)

Or

[ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Depending on your needs.

I go into more details on the difference between the two here:
[Thread safe way to copy a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791978/thread-safe-way-to-copy-a-map/25792259#25792259)

Comment: A `List` is not a `Set`. Whilst `Set` has `O(1)` search it also maintains unique objects which does _cost_.

Comment: The keys are in a set, and it does not maintain it, its the same as the search, it overrides if existing, it does no checks.

Comment: And how does it know `it overrides if existing` without carrying out any checks? Hashing and checking takes time.

Comment: O(1) does not necessarily mean an operation takes one step. It means the operation takes constant time. Although with millions of records, it is likely that some of the 'buckets' will contain multiple records, meaning that HashMap will take slightly more than O(1).